# SQL - Decaying Time Since Event Then Starting Over At the Next Event

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, missing-data

There are many similar questions and answers already posted but I could not find one with these differences. 1) The count of NULLs starts over, and 2) there is a math function applied to the replaced value.

An event either takes place or not (NULL or 1), by date by customer. Can assume that a customer has one and only one row for every date.

I want to replace the NULLs with a decay function based on number of consecutive NULLs (time from event). A customer can have the event every day, skip a day, skip multiple days. But once the event takes place, the decay starts over. Currently my decay is divide by 2 but that is for example.

| DT | CUSTOMER | EVENT | DESIRED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | b | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | b |  | 0.5 |
| 2022-01-03 | b |  | 0.25 |
| 2022-01-04 | b | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | b |  | 0.5 |

I can produce the desired result, but it is very unwieldy. Looking if there is a better way. This will need to be extended for multiple event columns.

```
create or replace temporary table the_data (
  dt date,
  customer char(10),
  event int,
  desired float)
;
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-01', 'a', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-02', 'a', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-03', 'a', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-04', 'a', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-05', 'a', 1, 1);

insert into the_data values ('2022-01-01', 'b', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-02', 'b', NULL, 0.5);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-03', 'b', NULL, 0.25);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-04', 'b', 1, 1);
insert into the_data values ('2022-01-05', 'b', NULL, 0.5);

with
    base as (
      select * from the_data
    ),
    find_nan as (
      select *, case when event is null then 1 else 0 end as event_is_nan from base
    ),
    find_nan_diff as (
      select *, event_is_nan - coalesce(lag(event_is_nan) over (partition by customer order by dt), 0) as event_is_nan_diff from find_nan
    ),
    find_nan_group as (
      select *, sum(case when event_is_nan_diff = -1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by customer order by dt) as nan_group from find_nan_diff
    ),
    consec_nans as (
      select *, sum(event_is_nan) over (partition by customer, nan_group order by dt) as n_consec_nans from find_nan_group
    ),
    decay as (
      select *, case when n_consec_nans > 0 then 0.5 / n_consec_nans else 1 end as decay_factor from consec_nans
    ),
    ffill as (
      select *, first_value(event) over (partition by customer order by dt) as ffill_value from decay
    ),
    final as (
      select *, ffill_value * decay_factor as the_answer from ffill
    )
select * from final
order by customer, dt
;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query could be simplified by using [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event.html) to generate subgrp helper column:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(event IS NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER 
                                                         ORDER BY DT) AS subgrp
  FROM the_data
)
SELECT *, COALESCE(EVENT, 0.5 / ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER, SUBGRP 
                                                  ORDER BY DT)) AS computed_decay
FROM cte
ORDER BY CUSTOMER, DT;
```

Output:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Without using `CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN 
    event = LAG(event,1, event) OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY dt)
    OR (event IS NULL AND LAG(event) OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY dt) IS NULL)
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS l
  FROM the_data

), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(l) OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY dt) AS SUBGRP
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *, COALESCE(EVENT, 0.5 / ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER, SUBGRP 
                                                  ORDER BY DT)) AS computed_decay
FROM cte2
ORDER BY CUSTOMER, DT;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14ebbeeb54dde34f69533f9085775d7f)**

Comment: Conditional change event. I did not know that function existed. Learn something new every day.  Thanks

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda Can you please offer a solution to this problem in sql server or oracle ?
I am struggling to solve this  using case with lag.Please if is possible.Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Florin It is outside the scope of this question and it should be a separate one, but here you are [SQL Server version db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14ebbeeb54dde34f69533f9085775d7f)

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda Thank you so much! i was so helpfull for me.Thank you!